# Backbone model is not saved

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var elementUrlRoot = api_url + '/elements';

var elementModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    'idAttribute': '_id' //mongoDB
    , 'urlRoot': elementUrlRoot
    , defaults: {
        "signature": "",
        "group": 0
    }//defaults
});

var elementCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: elementModel
    , 'url': elementUrlRoot
});

var testmodel = new elementModel({DOM_id: 111});

testmodel.save({signature: "test"},
    {
        error: function (model, response, options) {
            console.log('test model save error:', response);
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('test model save success');
        }
    }
);
```

My backbone model is not saved to the server when I update it.
I have set the urlRoot attribute of the Model (which according to the documentation should not be necessary). But there are still no HTTP requests being issued.

Update:

I have added a success method in the callback. It is being executed.
But there are no requests being sent to the server.

Update:

I found the error. I had added this code to save a whole collection.

```
Backbone.Collection.prototype.syncCollection = function (options) {
    console.log('syncing the collection');
    Backbone.sync("create", this, options);
};
```

It worked and I was able to save collections with it.
But it seems to have caused a problem with saving individual models. Requests are issued when I removed it.

Comment: Try adding an error callback to the `save` options.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have added this callback. But it does not produce any output to the console, so it's not called.

Comment: I see that my testmodel.save() returns an jqXHR object with status 204 (which I expect). But I see no activity on the network tab of the console.
Are the requests not shown on the console's network tab of Chrome?

Comment: The requests are shown in the networks tab. You might have a filter selected for only scripts, or something like that. Are any of the filter buttons selected? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network-files/network-overview.png

Comment: You want to select XHR if you want to see all of the AJAX requests from your models and whatnot.

Comment: You mean backbone-xhr-events? Anyway... I checked both my node server logs and the database. The elements are not updated when I issue a save() on them.

Comment: Okay, I noticed the requests are showing as images in the console.
`Request URL:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==`
There is nothing in the XHR tab. Just these image requests being issued.
On the server-side, I register no incoming requests.

On second thought - this is probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your urlRoot is needed because your model is not part of a collection.

Try unquoting your urlRoot attribute on the left side of the assignment
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot

Comment: It's fine not being in a collection. The docs say "Specify a urlRoot if you're using a model **outside** of a collection,..."

Comment: I understand, the OP said 
" I have set the urlRoot attribute of the Model (which according to the documentation should not be necessary)"
I was pointing out it was necessary because the model in question is outside the collection. Just trying clear up some confusion the OP seemed to have about the necessity of that urlRoot

Comment: Unquoting the key should not make any difference. And you really just added to the confusion, because the documentation says the urlRoot key is not required. My collection specifies the url, so any models that are taken from the collection should have the correct url.

Comment: My apologies if I added to your confusion.

Your example doesn't show the model being taken from the collection so I presumed you were using a standalone model which would in fact require you to use a urlRoot.

In your given example you would need a urlRoot on the model, that's the example you gave and I was just trying to make sure you were aware. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: @reggie
I dont have the rep to comment on your post but can you try something.

http://jsbin.com/zewuzomevo/edit?html,js,output
in a jsbin it seems to issue the request correctly (it fails by virtue of cross domain but the request is clearly issues in the network tab). I am guessing maybe some other code you have is causing the error, like perhaps loading a library the overwrites the backbone.sync function such as backbone-localstorage.

Comment: Okay thanks. I see the request in your example as well.